# Where to place Custom XConnect Model file in Azure

Tags: xconnect, azure, paas

I had a custom Model JSON file in on Premise environment under the `XConnect Project/App_Data/Models` folder.

Now we are moving to Azure. I see there are more roles in the Azure environment like `xc-collect`, `cortex-processing`, `cortex-reporting`. I don't have an idea in which project I need to place my custom file.

Please suggest to me how to find out the appropriate location for my new file.

Answer (score 6):

Deploy the JSON file to below locations on Azure:

1. `<Instance-Name>-xc-search` -> `App_Data/Models`
2. `<Instance-Name>-xc-search` -> `App_Data/jobs/continuous/IndexWorker/App_data/Models`
3. `<Instance-Name>-xc-collect` -> `App_Data/Models`
4. `<Instance-Name>-xc-refdata` -> `App_Data/Models`
5. `<Instance-Name>-ma-ops` -> `App_Data/Models`

For more details, refer to this blogpost https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2021/06/06/deploying-xconnect-customizations-on-azure/ which will guide you, if you’re customizing any of the marketing capability of Sitecore then on which app services on Azure you’ll place the related assemblies, XML or config.

Answer (score 5):

You will want to refer to the 'Deploy a custom model' documentation for your version. This link is for 10.0: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/sitecore-experience-platform/en/deploy-a-custom-model.html

From the docs, the roles that should be updated are:

- All instances of xConnect Collection
- All instances of xConnect Collection Search
- xConnect Search Indexer
- Marketing Automation Operations
- Marketing Automation Engine
- Content Delivery
- Content Management
- xDB Processing

Depending on how you configured your Azure installation, some of these roles may be merged together into a single app service.